# Fix UICollectionView cells in screen dynamically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm working on an tvOS app, I want to fix all cells in tv screen without scroll vertically or horizontally. Here cells count will count is dynamic, that's the main problem. I want to set all cells like this

For example:
If cell count is 4

[image]

If cell count is 5

[image]

If cell count is 9

[image]

If cell count is 11

[image]

Here dynamically need to set column's and row's and cell height and width.(Scroll not allowed)

My code is :

```
//Example array
var collectionViewArray:[UIColor] = [.brown, .red, .purple, .lightGray, .yellow, .black, .cyan, .magenta, .orange, .purple, .lightGray]

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return collectionViewArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TVMenuCollectionViewCell
    cell.cellView.backgroundColor = collectionViewArray[indexPath.row]
 return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let screenWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
    let screenHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
 return CGSize(width: (screenWidth-50)/4, height: (screenHeight-40)/3)
}
```

Actually if cells are more number, i need N x (N-1) Column's and row's.

Comment: What do you expect if the count is 15?

Comment: @Nikunj Kumbhani, actually I given only example. I want like this, because of count is actually " n "

Comment: Fine but for 15 and more you want 5 X 3 or 3 X 5?

Comment: @ Nikunj Kumbhani, first priority for column's number is heigh...Ithink 4x4 is better

Comment: So that means more then 11 it will be 4 X n right?

Comment: @ Nikunj Kumbhani, what ever it may be, once if we fix that later we will change the columns and rows.

Comment: @ Nikunj Kumbhani, actually I need N x (N-1) Column's and row's, if cells is more number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190007/discussion-between-nikunj-kumbhani-and-ios).

Answer (score 1):

Working code Swift 4

You need to use **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** method like this

```
class CardListViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    // UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout Delegate method

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let screenWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
        let screenHeight = collectionView.bounds.height

        if 0 ... 4 ~= collectionViewArray.count{
           return CGSize(width: (screenWidth - 30) / 2, height: (screenHeight - 30) / 2)
        }else if 5 ... 9 ~= collectionViewArray.count{
            return CGSize(width: (screenWidth - 40) / 3, height: (screenHeight - 40) / 2)
        }else{
            return CGSize(width: (screenWidth - 50) / 4, height: (screenHeight - 50) / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

From the Storyboard Set Section Insets Like this.

[image]

**Output**

[image]